# Correct usage of &. in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

What is the correct usage of &. in SCSS

In an SCSS file, what is the difference when you are using &. instead of .

```html
.text-field {
  .loading {
    -----
  }
  
  &.error {
    ------
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
&.error
```

The css is compiled as:

```
.text-field.error
```

While if you do not use & (as in your loading example) the compiled result is:

```
.text-field .loading
```

Which means the in the first example you are expecting the error class on the same 'parent' dom element, while in the latter you expect a child inside which is supposed to have the class `loading`.

So, there is no correct usage, it is a matter of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

`&` will join whatever follows it to the parent class.

In your example, it means `&.error` will evaluate to `.text-field.error` - styles that will be applied to any elements with both the `text-field` and `error` classes.

the `.loading` class however will evaluate to `.text-field .loading` - so elements with the loading class that have a parent element with the `text-field` class.

you can use `&` without the `.` as well, for example:

```
.text-field {
  &--loading {
    // styles
  }
}
```

will evaluate to a single `text-field--loading` class.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are good, but limited.

The use can be of other means.

Consider using the ampersand also to qualify context like so:

```
.child {
    .parent &{
    }
}
// gives .parent .child
```

This can also be used multiple times, while not rarely helpful and readable, this is still valid:

```
.child {
    & &{
    }
}
// gives .child .child
```

But can become nice with lists:

```
.a,.b{
    & + &{
    }
}
// gives .a + .a, .a + .b, .b + .a, .b + .b
```